# How to create a video background in a responsive web page?

Tags: html, css, video, responsive-design

I want to create a full screen video background in a responsive web page. If the page is responsive, the amount of data should correspond to the viewers device. Also, in this particular case, the scaled video will not be played if its to large compared to the display resolution of the viewers device. For this, I quote w3Schools:

> Note: Do not rescale video with the height and width attributes! Downsizing a large video with the height and width attributes forces a user to download the original video (even if it looks small on the page). The correct way to rescale a video is with a program, before using it on a page.

I need to use multiple videos with different resolution. I discovered that I can do it using media queries or maybe even JS, but what I don't know is how to optimize the relationship between the video resolution and the screen size. What is the optimum tolerance between them? The video will be scaled unless "it reached the limit" where the video source will be changed. What is the top or bottom limit for scaling a video? I am interested in ranges of this and any possible common ways for defining video sources regarding the screen sizes.

I welcome anybody to answer, but especially people with experience in working with video backgrounds and responsive web design.

I gave a HTML example to describe my dilemma. Also, if you see any errors, feel free to comment them.

```js
//maybe I can do it with JS
(function () {
  
  var mp4 = new Array();
  mp4[0] = "video_1920x1080.mp4";
  mp4[1] = "video_1280x720.mp4";
  mp4[2] = "video_640x480.mp4";
  mp4[3] = "video_320x240.mp4";

  var webm = new Array();
  webm[0] = "video_1920x1080.webm";
  webm[1] = "video_1280x720.webm";
  webm[2] = "video_640x480.webm";
  webm[3] = "video_320x240.webm";
  
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
  
  if (screen.width => 1280) {
     video.setAttribute("src", mp4[0]); 
     video.setAttribute("src", webm[0]); 
  }else if { // how should I continue?
  };
  
})();
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
@media all {
  video {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
       moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
         o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
           transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/94/fb/34/94fb342007a43e16c5b11e300abf713e.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  };
}
```

```html
<video poster="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/94/fb/34/94fb342007a43e16c5b11e300abf713e.jpg" autoplay="true" loop>
  /*maybe I can define it here*/
  <source src="video_1920x1080.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen and (min-width:1280px /*I am assuming this*/) and landscape">
  <source src="video_1920x1080.webm" type="video/webm" media="screen and (min-width:1280px /*I am assuming this*/ ) and landscape">
  <source src="video_1280x720.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen /* and (???) */ and landscape">
  <source src="video_1280x720.webm" type="video/webm" media="screen /* and (???) */ and landscape">
  <source src="video_640x480.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen /* and (???) */ and landscape">
  <source src="video_640x480.webm" type="video/webm" media="screen /* and (???) */ and landscape">
  <source src="video_320x240.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen /* and (???) */ and landscape">
  <source src="video_320x240.webm" type="video/webm" media="screen /* and (???) */ and landscape">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mathematically correct answer to the question of which video size should correspond to which screen size -- use the smallest file size that still has acceptable visual quality.  "Acceptable" is subjective and depends on the content and relative importance of the video, compression mechanism, etc.

I would strongly suggest that you not depend on e.g. `@media` queries to detect screen size, as a window resize would then trigger an ugly and bandwidth-wasting refresh and restart of a new video (possibly several, depending on how many different @media queries you set up).  Choose one video src on load, via javascript, essentially as you have it in your first code sample, and then leave it be; do not watch for resizes and try to update the video source after the fact.   (Err on the side of 'too small' -- unless your video is *extremely* short and well-compressed, 1920x1080 would be ridiculously large for a presumably cosmetic background effect.  If at all possible, consider switching from a video to a static image on mobile screen sizes.)

(The w3schools text you quote is somewhat misleading -- just like with `<img>` there's nothing inherently wrong with scaling a `<video>` within a reasonable range; they're just trying to warn people that scaling a full-frame video down to thumbnail size in the client is a waste of bandwidth compared to serving a thumbnail size video in the first place.)

Comment: Ok ty for your advices. I will definitely consider switching from a video to a static image on mobile screen sizes.

Comment: Ok , I did some testing. I hosted the test site on google drive to see if there are some problems when scaling a video. I did the most extreme negative scale/ from 1080p to 240p and the video played just fine. Apparently w3schools is outdated or wtever, Since I'm doing maximum presentation quality for a company, I will probably do one video resolution for desktops and tablets and other video res for mobiles (or just static image)... Or just maybe 3 videos, 1 for desktop, 1 for tablet and 1 for mobile for the sake of "optimum" amount of data.

Comment: "Apparently w3schools is outdated"  truer words were never spoke

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to decide what you are looking for speed or visuals. Because videos will cost you a lot. They are bandwidth eaters and bad for performance.

Most big websites are dropping videos for image background, for example PayPal.

### Questions:

> What is the top limit for scaling a video?

This not a web question more like a video/production question. Videos are same as images (they are sequence of images). So imagine you have a 600px x 600px image, and you want to use is as a background... That is the same result for videos.

Here is a video scale test:

I have a video which is: 640px x 360px

I scaled it up to full screen and then I zoomed it 3 times. So now this video is display on 3 times the resolution of your screen: (click on the video to zoom)

http://codepen.io/rema/pen/MKVQVR

### Code

Your code looks good and I would go with the CSS approach because it's valid.

*BTW: this won't work for IE8 and below, but even MS doesn't support them*

Just add `z-index: -1`.

### Conclusion

So there is no predefined limit, the limit is what your I likes. If you don't mind a pixelated video than you can use a 30px x 30px video and scale it up.

Comment: Yes, but if you do the negative scale, there could be some problems. If I do by your answer, then I would probably define queries in the manner where videos will be scaled up. Its a good idea...I m sorry, I maybe I didn't write with enough clarity: I am just interested to know what is the limit for the negative scale, since I need to do a page with a maximum presentation quality. As for performance, I was thinking of doing a "loading" screen before entering a single page application.